# POST Issue with PHP

Tags: php, forms, jquery-mobile, post

I have tried putting together a basic jQuery Mobile page that connects to another file on the same path of the server to send the data. I have tested the PHP by itself in the commented out part of code.

The PHP File - submit harvest.php

```
$dbConnection = mysqli_connect('*********', '*********', '*********', '*********');

/*
$variety  = "Aji Limon";
$picked   = "11";
$weight = "22";
*/

$variety  = $_POST['variety'];
$picked   = $_POST['picked'];
$weight = $_POST['weight'];

$query = "INSERT INTO `harvest` (`variety`, `picked`, `weight`) VALUES ('$variety', '$picked', '$weight')";

if (mysqli_query($dbConnection, $query)) {
    echo "Successfully inserted " . mysqli_affected_rows($dbConnection) . " row";
} else {
    echo "Error occurred: " . mysqli_error($dbConnection);
}

?>
```

And the html file - index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

    <!--Mobile Device Scaling -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0" />

</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="harvest">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
            <h1>Chilli Harvest</h1>
        </div>
    <div data-role="content">
    <form name="harvest" action="submitharvest.php" method="post" data-ajax="false">
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
          <label for="variety" class="select" >Variety:</label>
            <select name="variety" id="variety" data-theme="b">
                <option value="7 Pot Red">7 Pot Red</option>
                <option value="7 Pot Yellow">7 Pot Yellow</option>
                <option value="Aji Limon">Aji Limon</option>
            </select>
      </div>
      <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <label for="picked">Qty Picked:</label>
        <input type="range" name="picked" id="picked" value="1" min="0" max="200" step="1" data-theme="b" data-track-theme="c"/>
      </div>
      <div data-role="fieldcontain">
          <label for="weight">Weight (g):</label>
          <input type="number" name="weight" id="weight" value="" data-theme="b" />
      </div>
      <div data-role="fieldcontain">
        <input type="submit" value="Send" id="submit">
      </div>
    </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Having added the data-ajax="false" and even removing the entire query mobile framework I get the same problem of the php stating "Error Occurred" with no extra detail following it, I can't see anything going wring in the console either. Hopefully I'mm missing something very basic here? Please help.

So having tried a few things from the first couple of comments below - would it also be that the dbconnection being the culprit? I am using a NAS drive with personal MySQL database on it, do I need to speify the port number at the end? Currently I have:

$dbConnection = mysqli_connect('home IP Address:3306', 'username', 'password', 'databasename');

I have seen some connection strings like this where port numbers are involved:

$dbConnection = mysqli_connect('home IP Address', 'username', 'password', 'database name', 3306);

Which really adds to my confusion as I have tried all of the above and even putting the port number in "3306"... Stumped, anyone got any further ideas please?

Comment: Give us the output of "var_dump( $_POST );" as well as "echo $query;" on a valid form post.
It will give some more insight.

Comment: First, you should escape the POST variables before use in query, and second, try printing the $query so you can see the error by executing the query in console

Comment: I have used the echo $query before the else part of the if statement and the SQL is output as "INSERT INTO `harvest` (`variety`, `picked`, `weight`) VALUES ('Devils Rib', '1', '2')" which I confirm works when input into the MySQL database as is... Have to say I am very confused now.

Comment: You are not getting any further error details because you are just echoihg "Error occurred: " every time you get an error and mysqli_error doesn't exist as an option ---- http://www.php.net/manual-lookup.php?pattern=mysqli_error&lang=en&scope=404quickref  --- try this example for better structure using mysqli  with error reporting--- http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/code/434480/using-phpmysqli-with-error-checking

Comment: Thanks for the help, just gave that a go and I got the following: There was an error connecting to the database!

Unknown MySQL server host 'XXXXXXXXX.XXX:3306' (1)

Comment: so thats the problem then, its unable to connect to the host computer/server that has the database. If the database and PHP script to connect to database is on the same server change this "home IP Address:3306" to this --- localhost ---

Comment: I am using mobile phone on 3G network to access it and getting no joy, the home ip and dynamic IP address have been tried. The annoying thing is that if I uncomment the inputs on lines 3, 4 and 5 and comment out the POST part it works which outlines it's not the connection string! Being new to this I am very confused as that states to me the POST is wrong then when I run the with php form and POST it is saying it cannot login! catch 22 to me? The php and html file are on a hosted server, the web page is being ran from my mobile phone on 3G network and the MySQL database is at my home IP.

Comment: OK So this is really getting me down now as this should be quite simple... I have even set up a different MySQL server with the same issues. However the fault seems to be that if the php page that does the INSERT is executed by itself the data is inserted. However if the page is called from the input form I simply get the Can't connect to MySQL server on '12.34.56.789' (110) so issue has to be either with web server where files are hosted (tried 2!) or with the php? I need to know the answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out after many hours of wasting time the web server that it was hosted on was blocking the MySQL via it's Firewall, so all my check were ok but the web host firewall was to blame and the web company have added an exclusion to allow this to work!